# Override the position of bodypart with script on top of animation

Tags: unity, animation

I have a character with an Idle and Move animation.

Now I want to create an Attack animation. Here I want the hand to move towards the mouse position and back, using a script. The other hand should still follow the Idle or Move animation.

When I use a script in FixedUpdate() to do this the position of the hand still follows the animation. If I use LateUpdate() and set hand.transform.position, this seems to represent the local position and not global position.

Is there a proper way to create this Attack animation?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera;
    public Transform body;
    public Transform hand;
    public string button;
    public float time = 5f;
    public float begin = 3f;
    public float end = 6f;

    float step = 0f;

    bool pressed = false;
    float currentTime = 0f;
    int direction = 1;

    private void Start()
    {
        step = (end - begin) / time;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!pressed && Input.GetButtonDown(button))
        {
            pressed = true;
        }
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (pressed)
        {
            setCurrentTime();
            Vector2 mouse = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector2 direction = (mouse - (Vector2)body.position).normalized;
            hand.position = (Vector2)body.position + direction * (begin + (step * currentTime));

        }
    }

    void setCurrentTime()
    {
        currentTime = currentTime +  direction * Time.deltaTime;
        // At End 
        if (currentTime > time / 2)
        {
            float overhead = currentTime - (time / 2);
            currentTime = currentTime - overhead;
            direction = -1;
        }
        // Back at Begin
        if (currentTime < 0f)
        {
            pressed = false;
            currentTime = 0f;
            direction = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `transform.position` does not stop being in worldspace and switch to being in local space when you use it from `LateUpdate`. What specifically are you doing in `LateUpdate` (show all relevant code), and what specific symptoms are you observing that's leading you to believe it's in the wrong coordinate space? A common mistake here is accumulating a small delta from the current position, expecting these deltas to combine frame over frame, neglecting that the animation update is resetting you to the animated position just before `LateUpdate` runs - does that apply here?

Comment: @DMGregory I've added the code. The hand should move from a starting point next to the body (body.position + direction * begin). What happens is that the hand moves from the point where it currently is in the animation.

Comment: I think [Inverse Kinematics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Philipp I'm not sure if that's necessary since my character is only a body with two floating hands, but I'm going to check this out. Thanks